# Get the most common (frequent) string entry in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array with values in it (duh...).

Is there an easy way of getting the entry which occurs the most?
Something like

```
values[37].getMostOften();
```

Cheers :)

Comment: What do you do in the event of a tie?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var mostCommonValue = values.GroupBy(v => v)
                            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                            .Select(g => g.Key)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Reed's name carries a bit of weight you know :P

Comment: what does the 'v' and the 'g' equal to? I just tried the code but it returned nothing.

Comment: @Andy Those are lambda expressions - v is the individual value, and g would be each "group" (from GroupBy)

Comment: @Andy If values is an array, and it contains values, then this will return the most common value.